# Response headers in Angular interceptor

Tags: ajax, angularjs, restful-authentication

I have an interceptor for authentication.

I want to get a header out of the response when I get a 401 response error.

Interceptor is:

```
function ($httpProvider, fileUploadProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $localStorage) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       if ($localStorage.token) {
           config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
       }

       return config;
    },

    'responseError': function(response) {
       if (response.status === 401) {
          //$rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');  

          // WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"

          var authResult = response.headers('WWW-Authenticate');
          if (authResult.indexOf("invalid_token")>-1) {
              $localStorage.token = null;
              $timeout(function(){
                ;
              });
          }         
       }

       return response;
    }
  };
```

I want to get the WWW-Authenticate header from the response.

I can confirm the header is in the response of the web service call by looking at the network tab in Chrome developers tools. If I set a break point in the response handler function and then run console.log(response.headers()) in the console I get:

```
Object {}
undefined
```

How do I get to the response headers?

Answer (score 0):

The responseError function receives `rejection` instead of `response`.
Therefore if you want to access response headers, what you need is like below.

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        console.log(rejection.config.headers);
    }
}
```

I hope this would help you. :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice but that gives the request headers and not the response headers

Comment: Oh! I'm feeling silly. I will keep to find a solution.

Comment: I'm having exact the same issue. I can only get to the request headers, not the response headers. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although I know this is not answer and should post as comment, I post it here to use screen capture image.

I tried to get a response header with my test enviroment like below.

### nodejs server

```
res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'invalid_token');
res.status(401).send();
```

### angularjs

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        console.log(rejection.headers('WWW-Authenticate'));
    }
}
```

### Chrome dev tool screen capture

[image]

As you can see, I could get the response header correctly.
Therefore I think that there seems to be some problem in your server code where you set a response header.

Would you like to show us your chrome dev tool screen capture and your server code where you set the response header?

Comment: Can't paste a screen shot in a comment.
I definitely get the header in the response when I look at network tab
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer error="invalid_token"

Could this be a CORS thing?

Comment: Pasting a screen shot in your original quastion would help us to understand your situation. If your chrome receives the response header correctly, I think it could not be a CORS thing.

Comment: Thanks for screen shot. I got that the difference between my enviroment and yours is request method. Therefore I updated my test enviroment to use GET method instead of POST method, unfortunately my test works still fine. Ummm...